# Return a list of overdue non-summary tasks from a project using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am trying to extract the list of overdue non-summary tasks from a project using VBA. Till now I have this code:

```
Function GetOverdueTasks() As Tasks
    Dim ProjTasks As Tasks
    Dim ProjTask As Task
    Dim OverdueTasks As Tasks

    Set ProjTasks = ActiveProject.Tasks
    For Each ProjTask In ProjTasks
        If Not (ProjTask Is Nothing) Then
            If ProjTask.Summary = False Then
                If ProjTask.PercentComplete <> 100 And ProjTask.Finish < Now() Then
                    OverdueTasks.Add (Task)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ProjTask
    Set GetOverdueTasks = OverdueTasks
End Function
```

However, this fails in the line `OverdueTasks.Add (Task)` because the `Tasks` object `OverdueTasks` is not initialized. However, I am not able to find how to initialize the `Tasks` object. I tried using

```
Set OverdueTasks = New Tasks
```

But that fails with the Compile error "Invalid use of New keyword".

Any suggestions on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You're basically looking for a group of the overdue tasks. So make a `Collection`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TestFindOverdue()
    Dim overdueTasks As Collection
    Set overdueTasks = GetOverdueTasks

    '--- do something with the overdue tasks here
End Sub

Private Function GetOverdueTasks() As Collection
    Dim ProjTasks As Tasks
    Dim ProjTask As Task
    Dim overdueTasks As Collection

    Set ProjTasks = ActiveProject.Tasks
    For Each ProjTask In ProjTasks
        If Not (ProjTask Is Nothing) Then
            If ProjTask.Summary = False Then
                If ProjTask.PercentComplete <> 100 And ProjTask.Finish < Now() Then
                    overdueTasks.Add ProjTask, ProjTask.UniqueID
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ProjTask
    Set GetOverdueTasks = overdueTasks
End Function
```